# jQuery $(.button-class).click(function(){}); doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button, woocommerce

I tried to show an alert when a button is pressed, but it doesn't work, what can be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
    alert("Merge");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="17915" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Adaugă în coș</button>
```

Comment: Do not use images of code here. Add the actual html, js, etc to your question.

Comment: I added code, sorry!

Comment: Your code works, so there must be something else that you are not including in your question. Do you have any console errors, for example?

Comment: I have this error:  `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at ?product=...`

Comment: Well, you're not including jQuery. That is the reason.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Add the script tag (as in the snippet in your question). This should be put towards the top of your file, preferably in the `<head>` section.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: What if you try the same line I suggested?

Comment: This code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have this problem with your WordPress website.
and as you mentioned in the above comments that you have `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` error in the console, so let me clarify the issue.

`$` is not available globally in WordPress as `jQuery` object. You'll have to use `jQuery` keyword to access the jQuery then you can supply it is `$` so your code should be like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function () {
        alert('Merge');
    });
});
```

Or in a modern way

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function () {
        alert('Merge');
    });
})(jQuery);
```